# Problem with array in python and relative function declaring

Tags: python

I have some problem with python3 so here you can see a function so I'm trying to to see if there are some numbers equal to each other in a row or in column but 
when I recall the function the function gives me the value also if the condition in the function are not respect.

```py
def check(v):
    for i in range(0,9,3):
        if(v[i]==v[i+1]==v[i+2] and v[i]==0):
            return 10
        if(v[i]==v[i+1] and v[i]==v[i+2] and v[i]==1):
            return -10
    for i in range(0,3):
        if(v[i]==v[i+3]==v[i+6] and v[i]==0):
            return 10
        if(v[i]==v[i+3]==v[i+6] and v[i]==1):
            return -10
    if(v[0]==v[4]==v[8] and v[0]==0):
        return 10
    if(v[0]==v[4]==v[8] and v[0]==1):
        return -10
    if(v[2]==v[4]==v[6] and v[0]==0):
        return 10
    if(v[2]==v[4]==v[6] and v[0]==1):
        return -10
    return 15

v = [1,1,"_","_","_","_","_","_","_"]
a =check(v)
print(a)
```

Comment: Can you add the result of the print at the end, and specify the requirements for the function?

Comment: Please clarify why you consider it a problem that the code prints `-10`, and why you think that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the code using an IDE with breakpoints, or use print statements, or [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). If you need more help you will need to provide the requirements for that function, so we can understand what you are trying to achieve better.